# Problems sorting consumed API data

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a simple axios API request in my Vue.js component and it is placed in mounted(). Actually it's the only thing in that lifecycle.

Inside beforeUpdate() I run a method that sorts the content of the API results. This is also the only thing going on in that lifecycle.

The whole thing worked. I ran npm run serve and saw the correct results with my own eyes.

So - I got on with my code and started working on a method that is not related to the mentioned code in any respect. Saved it and so the server refreshed and I went to my browser only to find that the original code had crashed and the API results where gone.

I removed my changes to the method - even if it was not related - and saved again. No fix. API results still gone. So I removed the whole method - but no remedy.

The mounted() search and the method that once was working is still unchanged.

I've been working this problem all day. Some times I get the right results back - without actually understanding what I did - but then when I change something else - they're gone again.

I honestly don't think there is anything wrong with my code and I'm not getting any error messages.  What else could it be that's causing this?

EDIT: Removed display of package.json - since not relevant.

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import moment from 'moment';
moment.locale('nb');  

export default {
  name: 'Regobs',
  data: function() {
    return {
      info: null,
      sortert: [],
      authors: [],
      authorsUnike: [],
      test: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    rettTid(dato) {
      var a = moment(dato).format('L');
      var b = moment(dato).format('LT');
      var c = a + " " + b;
      return c
    },

    sortering() {
      this.test = "sortering";
      var i = 0;      
      while(i < 10 ){
      // Hvis istykkelse ikke er registrert, ta den bort
        var istykkelse 
        var iskommentar
        if (this.info[i].IceThickness == null || this.info[i].IceThickness.Comment == null) {
          istykkelse = 0;   
          iskommentar = "";     
        } else {
          istykkelse = this.info[i].IceThickness.IceThicknessSum; 
          iskommentar = this.info[i].IceThickness.Comment;
        }
        // Hvis IceCoverObs ikke finnes
        var iscover
        var iscoverobs
        if (this.info[i].IceCoverObs == null) {
          iscoverobs = "";    
          iscover = "";      
        } else {
          iscover = this.info[i].IceCoverObs.IceCoverName;
          iscoverobs = this.info[i].IceCoverObs.IceCapacityName;
        }
        this.sortert.push( [
          { 'LocationName': this.info[i].ObsLocation.LocationName }, 
          { 'DtObsTime': this.rettTid(this.info[i].DtObsTime) },
          { 'IceThicknessSum': istykkelse },
          { 'IceCoverName': iscover },
          { 'IceCapacityName': iscoverobs }, 
          { 'IceThicknessComment': iskommentar }, 
          { 'Latitude': this.info[i].ObsLocation.Latitude },
          { 'Longitude': this.info[i].ObsLocation.Longitude }, 
          { 'ObsLocationID': this.info[i].ObsLocation.ObsLocationID }
        ] )        
        this.authors.push( this.info[i].Observer.ObserverName )
        i++;     
      }
      return this.sortert
    },
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .post('https://api.regobs.no/v4/Search', {'NumberOfRecords': '10', 'SelectedGeoHazards': '[70]', 'Extent': { 'TopLeft': { 'Latitude': '60.14', 'Longitude': '10.21' }, 'BottomRight': { 'Latitude': '60.04', 'Longitude': '10.35' }}},  { headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/json'}})
      .then(response => (this.info = response.data ));
  },
  beforeUpdate () {
    this.sortering();
  },
  filters: {
    rundAv: function(value) {
      if(!value) {
        value = 0;
      }
      value = Math.round(value * Math.pow(10, 2)) / Math.pow(10, 2);
      return value;
    },
    meterTilCm: function(value) {
      var a = value * 100;
      var b = a + " cm";
      return b;
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

EDIT: So I changed the code according to @T.Short's anwer - and removed the whole beforeUpdate. That worked just fine on localhost, but the component crashed when deployed on netlify. The console also started showing the error:

```
[Vuew warn] You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
```

I also tried to refine the mounted() code a bit:

```
  mounted () {
    this.pending = true;
    axios
      .post('https://api.regobs.no/v4/Search', {'NumberOfRecords': '10', 'SelectedGeoHazards': '[70]', 'Extent': { 'TopLeft': { 'Latitude': '60.14', 'Longitude': '10.21' }, 'BottomRight': { 'Latitude': '60.04', 'Longitude': '10.35' }}},  { headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/json'}})
      .then(response => { this.info = response.data })
      .catch(error => {this.error = error })
      .finally( function() { 
        this.sortering()
        this.pending = false });
  }
```

But still no joy. Actually, Vue DevTools shows that pending is true all the time - and that's also a little strange (to me). The API is consumed, but my method() (sortering) does not happen...

Comment: Show us the Vue code 

Comment: OK T.Short . I was tryin' to keep it "short" :-D

Comment: Why are you calling `this.sortering()` inside beforeUpdate() `

Comment: Actually - that is a mistake. I guess it could work just fine inside mounted(). I've tried putting it there of course - but it just does not work. That's why it now lives in the place where it (mistakenly) was when the code actually worked ...

Comment: But from what I can understand, don't you want to call `this.sortering()` after you receive a response from the request?

Comment: Yes - that is correct, sir. I've actually got a live version of that code when it was working. I figured I'd keep it just to prove to myself that I'm not delusional ---> https://holeonice.netlify.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments it seems to me you should be doing it like this:

```js
mounted () {
    axios
      .post('https://api.regobs.no/v4/Search', {'NumberOfRecords': '10', 'SelectedGeoHazards': '[70]', 'Extent': { 'TopLeft': { 'Latitude': '60.14', 'Longitude': '10.21' }, 'BottomRight': { 'Latitude': '60.04', 'Longitude': '10.35' }}},  { headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/json'}})
      .then(response => {
           this.info = response.data;
           this.sortering();
      } );
  }
```

You want to wait for the response to arrive, set `this.info` and then call the function.

### EDIT

So, I managed to get it to work. You have two culprits:

1. `{{ forfattere(authors) }}` - Refactor this, it's causing infinite loops
2. This line of code:

```
<span :class="[ tykkelsen ? 'green' : 'red']">{{ sjekkTykkelsen(item[2].IceThicknessSum) }} cm</span>
```

This is also causing the infinite loop.

Here is a working sandox: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-lumiere-v00c2

Comment: Of course - you are correct T.Short. My, very inexperienced, other attempt had the call for sortering() outside the the response. That did not work - and I guess that is because the response was not "in" yet ...? And thank you so much for helping a novice out so late at night!

Comment: You're welcome. And remember, computers never lie 

Comment: Ah - one problem though @T.Short. Moving the method call into the response caused the app to crash wen deployed to netlify. It works locally, but I do get a warning that I did not get earlier ([Vuew warn] You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.).

Comment: Probably because you have `beforeUpdate () {  this.sortering();  },` This seems like a loop inducing bit of code

Comment: But I don't anymore. I'll edit the original post a bit.

Comment: Try simplifying `this.sortering()` for a moment. Make it just log something. If it works then you know it's something you are doing inside that huge function

Comment: What I can see it that you are looping 10 times and each time updating `this.sortert` and `this.authors` which is probably re-rending your component each time, which is bad practice anyway. Build the arrays first and then push them once the loop is finished so you only re-render once.

Comment: Removed everything but this.sortert = 1; from this.sortering() - but Vue DevTools still says this.pending = true. So there must be something wrong with mounted() - right?

Comment: It's all a bit messy from my point of vue. Would you be able to create some kind of sandbox replicating your setup? (Enough to reproduce your error)

Comment: Kindof. Reduced to one component (not working tough) - and it complaints that Buefy is not used - wich i s true for that component --> https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-resonance-o9w8d?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark  Messy - yes :-o

Comment: So from this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-lumiere-v00c2 can't get it to give me the warning

Comment: Added the solution to my post - your codes needs a bit of a refactor really. It's hard to manage it - but it works currently

Comment: Wow!
1. As the amateur I am - I would never have figured this one out! 
2. I learned so much from studying your "washed" code!
3. There are still things that you did that I do not grasp, but I will do the due dilligence and study them harder.
4. You may have saved lives. This page is made for locals that want to go out ice skating on a local lake - and it's not allways safe. 
5. If your're ever in Norway I owe you a hotel room and a pizza (I run a small hotel and a pizzeria for a living).
6. If you move to Norway - I can get you a very well paid job!
7. Thank you - a whole lot!
Wow!

Comment: Happy to help  and I may hold you too that  (my gf wants to visit Norway)